# How can I exit a program running in the repl in common lisp?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

when I run a function in the repl, the repl becomes a place to input user values.

For example:

```lisp
(defun asking-questions ()
  (let ((firstname (prompt-read "What is the firstname of the contact?"))
    (email (prompt-read "What is their email?"))
    (company (prompt-read "What is the company name?"))

.... ))

(defun prompt-read (question)
  (format *query-io* "~a:  " question)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
```

Sometimes, I want to 'cleanly' close the program mid-way through because I am experementing with the `email` input (for example.

My desired outcome is to press a set of keys that allow me to go back to the `package>`. How do I accomplish that?

I use emacs + SBCL.

Comment: If you are using Slime `C-c C-b` drops you into the debugger and you can abort the program from there by choosing an appropriate restart.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Can you add it as an answer please? Thank you Ad

Comment: `C-c C-c` (then `q`) works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Slime with emacs you can press <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-b</kbd> to drop into the debugger where you can abort the program by choosing an appropriate restart.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, in a terminal directly interfacing with the REPL the C-c interrupt command should bring you to the debugger, where you can abort the computation up to the toplevel loop.